# django 3.2- error creating superuser in sqllite3

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

```
PS C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\PycharmProjects\EnhanceImage> python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'abdullazia'): admin
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line      
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute 
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 157, in handle 
    validate_password(password2, self.UserModel(**fake_user_data))
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 44, in validate_password       
    password_validators = get_default_password_validators()
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 19, in get_default_password_validators
    return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 30, in get_password_validators 
    validators.append(klass(**validator.get('OPTIONS', {})))
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 174, in __init__
    with gzip.open(password_list_path, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  File "C:\Users\Abdulla Zia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\gzip.py", line 57, in open
    raise TypeError("filename must be a str or bytes object, or a file")
TypeError: filename must be a str or bytes object, or a file
```

performed all the migrations still getting this error. I've deleted database file and created new one still getting the same error. server is up and in running without any errors

Comment: Show your `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` setting (in `settings.py`)

Comment: AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make migration and try to create the superuser
try this

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

or try this when its your initial migration

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i already tried these commands. i didn't work! same issue. i even deleted sqldb3 file and again ran these commands in same order as mentioned, still getting error